# Why does AsyncStorage save an empty array with the first click and then save the entered value only with the second button click in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage, react-native-state

I try to save the tasks in my ToDo app with AsyncStorage so that they can be retrieved after an app restart.

So far I have managed to save the tasks. However, an empty array is always saved in the first run. If I want to create a new task, it only saves it the second time I click the button. Logical if the whole thing runs asynchronously. I just can't figure out where my fault is. I would be very happy to receive help and tips.

Here you can see the empty array when creating the first task:
[Reactotron Empty Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJQpz.jpg)

And here you can see the first value get's saved after i created the second task:
[Reactotron AsyncStorage after second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itc8o.jpg)

First Part:

```
if (__DEV__) {
  import('./ReactotronConfig').then(() => console.log('Reactotron Configured'));
}
import Reactotron, { asyncStorage } from 'reactotron-react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Task from './components/Task';

export default function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
      const jsonValue2 = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      if (jsonValue2 !== null) {
        setTaskItems(jsonValue2);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };

  const storeData = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'TASKS',
        JSON.stringify(taskItems)
      );
      return jsonValue;
      Reactotron.log(jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    storeData();
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
    setTask(null);
  };

  const completeTask = (index) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  };

  const bearyDustLogo = require('./assets/bearydust-logo-bear-with-text.png');
```

Second Part:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        {/* Aufgaben für heute */}

        <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.headerWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>StandUp Aufgaben</Text>
            <Image style={styles.tinyLogo} source={bearyDustLogo}></Image>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.items}>
            {/* Aufgabenbereich */}
            {taskItems.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() => completeTask(index)}
                >
                  <Task text={item} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

      {/* Aufgabe erstellen */}

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={'Ey! Lass was machen'}
          value={task}
          onChangeText={(text) => setTask(text)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            handleAddTask();
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it's first saving and then it's updating the array, so you will always be one step behind on your storage:

```
const handleAddTask = () => {
    storeData(); // here you are handling the save
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]); // but you update the values only here
    setTask(null);
  };
```

To keep your code simple I would suggest you to save each time you have an update on your `taskItems` but keep in mind you don't need to update the first time you load from storage, so something like this should work:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
      const jsonValue2 = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      if (jsonValue2 !== null) {
        setTaskItems(jsonValue2);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  };

  const storeData = async () => {
    // commenting this line as you don't need to clean the storage each time you write something on it, as you'll just override the existing key 'TASKS'
    // await AsyncStorage.clear();
    
    // here you validate if the data was loaded already before starting watching for changes on the list
    if (!loading) {
      try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'TASKS',
          JSON.stringify(taskItems)
        );
        return jsonValue;
        Reactotron.log(jsonValue);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    storeData()
  }, [taskItems])

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    // won't need this line anymore as now everything you update your list it will be saved.
    // storeData();
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setTaskItems([...taskItems, task]);
    setTask(null);
  };

  const completeTask = (index) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
    // this will trigger a save as well
    setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
  };

  const bearyDustLogo = require('./assets/bearydust-logo-bear-with-text.png');
```

This way you will always save any updates on the task list and will prevent to save then as empty when first rendering your component.

Success on your project.

Comment: I love you dude :D you saved my brain from exploding. I had to save your if statement in the useEffect Hook in an asynchronous function and then call it in the useEffect. Otherwise I had a bug that await can only be used in an asynchronous function. Now it saves every entry in the memory and deletes it as soon as I mark the task as completed. You're my hero, thanks alot!

Comment: Nice to hear it helped! I've updated the code with the async function so anyone can use it as future reference.